# edit spinner in one activity from another activity

Tags: android-activity, android-spinner

i created Activity5 for manage values on other activities...

in Activity3 i have a spinner...

```
Spinner spinner1;
ArrayList<String> SAlist;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

  Intent intent = getIntent();
  ArrayList<String> SAList =  intent.getStringArrayListExtra("StringArrayList");


  spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

  ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,SAList);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adp);      


}
```

i think if i build new spinner (for showing it to user) in activity5 and edit it , then passing array list of this spinner to activity3, this is possible...

Activity5:

```
Spinner sp;
EditText et;
ArrayList<String> li;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity5);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

  li=new ArrayList<String>();
  li.add("first item");
  sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  Button butt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  Button butt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  add();

  butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        li.add(et.getText().toString());
        et.setText(null);
        add();
        }
});

  butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity5.this, MainActivity3.class);
      intent.putStringArrayListExtra("StringArrayList", li);
      startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
private void add() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,li);
        sp.setAdapter(adp);
           }
```

but when i launch app and open activity3 it shows "unfortunately app has stopped" !!!
help me plz!

Answer (score 1):

when you open activity3 from main menu, on that event your getting SAList null,
try doing this,when SAList is null it will show empty spinner.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getStringArrayListExtra("StringArrayList")!=null)
    {
        ArrayList<String> SAList =  intent.getStringArrayListExtra("StringArrayList");
    }else
    {
        ArrayList<String> SAList=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```